# use spark cassandra package in Azure Data Factory

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, pyspark, azure-data-factory

I created a pyspark script which works fine when I execute it with `spark-submit`:

```
spark-submit --packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.11:2.0.6 --conf spark.cassandra.connection.host=12.34.56.68 test_cassandra.py
```

As I am working with Azure Data Factory, I would like to execute this job in ADF too. I created the following job :

```
{
    "name": "spark write to cassandra",
    "type": "HDInsightSpark",
    "policy": {
        "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
        "retry": 0,
        "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
        "secureOutput": false
    },
    "typeProperties": {
        "rootPath": "dev/apps/spikes",
        "entryFilePath": "test_cassandra.py",
        "sparkConfig": {
            "packages": "datastax:spark-cassandra-connector:2.0.7-s_2.10",
            "conf": "spark.cassandra.connection.host=12.34.56.78"
        },
        "sparkJobLinkedService": {
            "referenceName": "linkedServiceStorageBlobHDI",
            "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
        }
    },
    "linkedServiceName": {
        "referenceName": "linkedServiceHDI",
        "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
    }
}
```

I thought it would be enough, but there is apparently a problem with the package. I received the error :

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra. Please find packages at https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SPARK/Third+Party+Projects

Can you help me to configure properly my activity to make it run ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The options as they are in spark-submit are a little bit different in ADF.

`--packages` becomes `spark.jars.packages`
and
`--conf spark.cassandra.connection.host=12.34.56.78` becomes `"spark.cassandra.connection.host": "12.34.56.78"`

the final code is :

```py
{
    "name": "spark write to cassandra",
    "type": "HDInsightSpark",
    "policy": {
        "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
        "retry": 0,
        "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
        "secureOutput": false
    },
    "typeProperties": {
        "rootPath": "dev/apps/spikes",
        "entryFilePath": "test_cassandra.py",
        "sparkConfig": {
            "spark.jars.packages": "datastax:spark-cassandra-connector:2.0.7-s_2.10",
            "spark.cassandra.connection.host": "12.34.56.78"
        },
        "sparkJobLinkedService": {
            "referenceName": "linkedServiceStorageBlobHDI",
            "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
        }
    },
    "linkedServiceName": {
        "referenceName": "linkedServiceHDI",
        "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
    }
}
```

Comment: You saved my day. Thanks  a lot. Can you pls share document link from where I can get these references?

Comment: @HemantChandurkar I found some of the information on spark configuration page https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html

Answer (score -1):

The failure is caused by the dependency package is not defined correctly. You can follow the document below to include all your dependency jars in the subdirectory "jars" of the rootPath of the activity:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-spark#folder-structure

Or you can use the spark built-in mechanism to manage dependency by customize spark configurations. Please refer to the doc below for details:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#available-properties